# 404 Error when sending POST requests to API in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, post, httprequest

I am trying to set up an API in a docker container and whenever I send an HTTP POST Request it fails with a 404 error. The interesting thing is that when I run the API with nodemon it works perfectly fine.

I am using the command `docker run -p 8080:8080 IMAGE` to run the API.

Here is the route for the post request and the controller.

`router.post('/', linux_aps_controller.linux_aps_send_log);`

```
exports.linux_aps_send_log = (req, res, next) => {
const log_to_send = new Linux_APS({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    device_id: req.body.device_id
});
log_to_send
    .save()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result),
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Created new Linux APS log successfully',
            createdLog: {
                _id: result._id,
                device_id: result.device_id,
                request: {
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: process.env.LINUX_ENDPOINT + result._id
                }
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the dockerfile itself (and the rest of your code, is it node/express?), it's hard to tell what has gone wrong here.

Try using a different base image like node:12.17, see the following sample:

```
FROM node:12.17.0 

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is related, but I also got stuck with a python script in a Docker container not being able to call an API endpoint. I discovered that this was due to the proxy settings in my Dockerfile. I'm on a corporate intranet that requires a proxy to access the internet. The API I'm trying to reach is also on the intranet. In my Docker file, I had to specify the API host name I was trying to reach with:

ENV NO_PROXY = .intranet.net